# Trouble verifying Facebook publish_actions permission

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully logged into Facebook and asked for publish_actions permission. The permission is granted, as I can readily verify on `https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications` and also by calling

```
-(void) whatPermissionsDoIHave
{
  [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions"
    completionHandler:^(
      FBRequestConnection *connection,
      NSDictionary* result,
      NSError *error
    ) {
       //do checks in here
      }
  }];
}
```

So I know for certain that I have permission. However, whenever it's time to share, my permission check returns false. I will now show my permission check

```
+ (BOOL)hasWritePermissions
{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) return NO;
    NSLog(@"So the session is at least open");
    return [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@[@"publish_actions"]] != NSNotFound;
}
```

So am I missing something else? Perhaps something I should have done in AppDelegate or such? Thanks for any insight.

Right now the only call I am making in AppDelegate is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                        NSLog(@"In fallback handler");
                    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions property is an array of strings, but you're calling indexOfObject on another array, which is probably why it can't find it. Try this instead:

```
return [FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] != NSNotFound;
```